# Search by list type field in Spring Data to check if empty or not

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a Project entity and a separate entity to represent a project assigned to a user

```
public class Project {
    // other fields    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project")
    private List<UserProject> projectAssignedUsers;

}

public class UserProject {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

I need to write 2 separate queries that return the list of assigned projects and unassigned projects, this is what I have:

```
@Query("from Project p where p.country = :country and p.projectAssignedUsers != null order by p.name asc")
List<Project> getAssignedProjectsByCountry(String country, Pageable pageable);

@Query("from Project p where p.country = :country and p.projectAssignedUsers = null order by p.name asc")
List<Project> getUnassignedProjectsByCountry(String country, Pageable pageable);
```

However, I'm getting this error:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

How could I write such a query?

Answer (score 0):

This is your first query transformed to plain SQL:

```sql
select project0_.id as id1_1_, project0_.country as country2_1_, project0_.name as name3_1_ from project project0_ 
cross join user_project projectass1_ 
where project0_.id=projectass1_.project_id 
and project0_.country='Country' 
and (. is not null) 
order by project0_.name asc
```

The problem is here: `and (. is not null)`.

You can fix it using joins:

```
@Query(value = "from Project as p left join p.projectAssignedUsers as u where p.country = :country and u is not null")
List<Project> getAssignedProjectsByCountry(String country, Pageable pageable);
```

```
@Query(value = "from Project as p left join p.projectAssignedUsers as u where p.country = :country and u is null")
List<Project> getUnassignedProjectsByCountry(String country, Pageable pageable);
```